# How does one derive $O(n \log{n}) =O(n^2)$?

Tags: asymptotics

I was studying time complexity where I found that time complexity for sorting is $O(n\log n)=O(n^2)$. Now, I am confused how they found out the right-hand value. According to this $\log n=n$. So, can anyone tell me how they got that value?

[Here](http://www.seas.gwu.edu/~ayoussef/cs212/npcomplete.html#yesno) is the link where I found out the result.

Comment: Why aren't editors checking the link before changing big O to little O? The link clearly uses big O.

Comment: The "accepted" answer deals with little-o asymptotics although the question is about Big-O asymptotics. OP: can you explain?

Comment: @Did I was about to ask the very same thing.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff Priority attribution: you mentioned all this, well before my comment...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f(x)=\mathcal{O}(g(x))$ means that $f$ is asymptotically smaller or equal to $g$. This means that $|f(x)|\le c|g(x)|\quad \forall x$ for some constant c.

Now in your example, $$n\log n \le n^2$$

This does not say that $n=\log n$, but instead, that $\log n\le n$. In other words, that $\log n$ is asymptotically smaller or equal to $n$, or, in Big-O notation, $\log n = \mathcal{O}(n)$.

Comment: You're talking about Big O but using little o's?

Comment: @PeterTamaroff, no, I am talking about little o's, im just used to calling the entire subject BigO notation ;)

Comment: OK, but the OPs question is about $n\to\infty$ and sequences and Big O, not functions and quotients and Little O. You seem to have missed this.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff I didnt. I answered the OPs question in the last line. I avoided the formal definition using quantors for the exact reason that I assumed that that was what the OP hadnt understood.

Answer (score 6):

No, $O(n\log n)=O(n^2)$ doesn't mean $\log n=n$.

Recall that $f(n)=O(g(n))$ means there exists $C$ and $N$ such that $|f(n)|\leq C g(n)$ for $n\geq N$. For example, $\log n$ is $O(n)$. Thus, $n\log n$ is $O(n^2)$.

What I guess they are trying to say is that if something is $O(n\log n)$ then it is $O(n^2)$, that is $n\log n$ is $O(n^2)$. Note that the reverse usage $$O(n^2)=O(n\log n)$$ would be incorrect. A better notation might be $$O(n\log n)\subseteq  O(n^2)$$

Comment: +1 - this is exactly why I much, much prefer the subset language ($\subseteq$ and $\in$) for questions about big-O and related notations.

Answer (score 2):

That's not what $O$ means!

When people write $f(x) = O(g(x))$ (for large $x$) they're not saying something about the specific, exact form of $f$. What this notation means is that there's some (possibly unknown number) $M$ such that
$$|f(x)| \le M |g(x)|$$
for all big enough $x$. Intuitively,

> $f(x)$ is **no bigger than** $g(x)$ for large $x$ - at least up to a constant factor.

In this case, they're saying that

- the number of steps sorting takes is no more than $\text{something}\times n\log n$.
- the function $n\log n$ isn't any bigger than $An^2$ for large $n$, for some $A$.

Answer (score 1):

What this equation means is that the class $O(n\log n)$ is included in the class $O(n^2)$. That is, if a sequence is eventually bounded above by a constant times $n \log n$, it will eventually be bounded above by a (possibly different) constant times $n^2$. Can you prove this? The notation is somewhat surprising at first, yes, but you get used to it.

Comment: but why only n^2?can we use some other constant?

Comment: @nikhil Yes. In fact, $O(n \log n) = O(n^{1+\epsilon})$ for any $\epsilon>0$. So for example, we have $O(n \log n) = O(n^{3})$ and $O(n \log n) = O(n^{1.5})$ and $O(n \log n) = O(n^{1.0000001})$.